# Как реализовать поведение такого компонента ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

Пишу форму регистрации, в которой, среди прочих, есть следующие секции:

1. Образование
2. Язык
3. Опыт работы

В каждой секции есть соответствующие поля для заполнения, и каждая оканчивается кнопкой-компонентом React, **которую я и не могу понять, как реализовать**. Вот что она, по задумке, умеет:

- У неё есть value='+', меняется по клику на '-' и обратно
- Кликнута, когда value="+": она отрисовывает после текущего дива/элемента, в котором находится, ещё один точно такой же (например, если находится в секции "Язык", то отрисовывает ещё одну такую же секцию, чтобы юзер мог указать данные о своём втором языке)
- Кликнута, когда value="-": удаляет этот элемент. Не с конца, а именно тот, который отрисовала эта данная кнопка.

**Не возникает вопросов**: как по клику менять value и запускаемую функцию; и даже вполне понятно, что в state должны быть массивы для каждого типа секции, которые содержат соответствующие элементы, и в которые их можно добавлять по клику той кнопки, например:

```
this.state = {
educations:[education],
languages:[language, language, language],
experiences:[exp]
}
```

и потом рендерить каждый массив при помощи map.

**Что мне не понятно:**

- Что из всего этого (секция, кнопка, вся форма регистрации) должно быть компонентом-классом, компонентом-функцией, элементом-константой?
- Если кнопка - компонент, как она будет менять state формы, добавляя элементы в массивы? Вроде бы в React так делать нельзя. Если компонент - фор
- Как кнопка будет понимать, в какой секции она находится, чтобы добавить именно такую же?
- Как удалять из массива именно тот элемент, возле которого был кликнут '-'?

Comment: 1) Компоненты - форма и секции (инпут с кнопкой, если они не хитрые какие-нибудь, точнее сложно сказать, главное не перемудрить); 2) В стейте формы хранятся данные, у компонента формы есть методы (inputAdd, inputRemove) меняющий эти данные, он передается в дочерний компонент (секцию) и вызывается при каких-либо действиях внутри секции; 3) Каждая секция - реиспользуемый компонент, соответственно у каждой свой стейт, внтрь передаются скажем name, state (формы), метод меняющий state (формы); 4) В метод меняющий стейт передается name и id. Как-то примерно так ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Двухстороняя привязка функций решила мой вопрос: нужные функции, работающие со state, просто передаются в дочерние компонента, то есть в кнопки, в качестве значений атрибутов onClick,и id, который даётся секции, когда она добавляется в state. По id отфильтровывается массив секций в state.
Пока что для добавления каждого типа секции написал свою функцию, но в ближайшем будущем попробую эти функции сделать универсальными (например, принимающими массив секций соответствующего типа для добавления новой секции именно в него)
Большая благодарность MedvedevDev за помощь!